# Combining two TAB files in MapBasic - losing data

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am using mapbasic to perform some calculations on a table. Everything is fine until I combine two .tab files.

[image]

Both files have identical table structures, however upon combination some numerical (float) values are being set as 0.

Values from HUNDRED_CL:

[image]

Values after combining the files:

[image]

The CR1 data is fine, but as soon as I append the CL1 data to it, some TO values become 0, can somebody assist?

Table structures for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What SQL statement do you use the join the two tables?

Comment: Insert Into HUNDRED_CR1 ( COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9) Select COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9 From HUNDRED_CL1

Comment: That's the Insert statement. What Select statement are you using to join the two tables?

Comment: I'm not joining the tables beforehand, I'm just inserting everything from HUNDRED_CL1 into HUNDRED_CR1 to make a combined file. Selected snippet from the section of the code:

http://pastebin.com/ex1YwvQT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert statement only specifies to insert the first 9 columns into the destination table.

The column where the values are zero, is column 10.

Unless the column names change, I would recommend that you use the real column names that will make it a lot easier to read.